# How to get a an object with a fixed string from an array in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, object

I have an array of objects whose length can change dynamically but the max is always 8. Every object has a fixed string which describes it, for example:

```
array.get(0).getString() = apple
array.get(1).getString() = blueberry
array.get(2).getString() = banana
array.get(3).getString() = cherry
array.get(4).getString() = coconut
array.get(5).getString() = grapefruit
array.get(6).getString() = lemon
array.get(7).getString() = orange
```

Depending on how many objects and what type of string I get from an api, I want to hide or show a View. I'm currently using a switch statement like this:

```
if (array.toArray().length == 1) {

        switch (array.get(0).getString()) {
            case "apple":
                ...
                break;
            case "blueberry":
                ...
                break;
            case "banana":
                ...
                break;
            case "cherry":
                ...
                break;
            case "coconut":
                ...
                break;
            case "grapefruit":
                ...
                break;
           case "lemon":
                ...
                break;
            case "orange":
                ...
                break;

        } else if (array.toArray().length == 2) {

              switch (array.get(0).getString()) {
              ...
              }

              switch (array.get(1).getString()) {
              ...
              }
        }
```

I do this 8 times and every time I have to add a new switch statement. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Just a nitpick, but "grapefruit" has 10 characters.

Comment: Why not ``array.size()`` rather than ``array.toArray().length``?

Comment: You are allowed to have switch statements longer than 8 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loops and you can use Map's to avoid switch statements.

```java
List<YourCustomObject> arr = getObjectsFromAPI();
Map<String, Boolean> fruitVisibility = new HashMap<>();
fruitVisibility.put("apple", true); // Let' say apple is visible
fruitVisibility.put("orange", false); // Orange is not visible
// ..... and so on

for(YourCustomObject obj : arr){
  if(fruitVisibility.containsKey(obj.getString()))
     view.setVisible(fruitVisibility.get(obj.getString()));
}
```

Or you can use the way you are trying to do.

```java
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
  switch(array.get(i).getString()){
    //    case ..
    // ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use iterators, kind of like bellow:

```
 Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     System.out.println(iterator.next());
  }
```